# Uncaught TypeError in Roundcube/MarkasJunk2 Plugin

Tags: javascript, roundcube

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when running Roundcube with MarkasJunk2.

It seems to happen in `rcmail_markasjunk2_update()`

and seems to be relating to the following line:

```
if (rcmail.env.markasjunk2_override || rcmail.is_multifolder_listing()) {
```

My first guess was that it's an environmental variable that isn't being set (hence rcmail.env) but it actually seems like rcmail.is_multifolder_listing() doesn't exist. Is there a configuration setting I need to change to enable this?